# Finding the limit of a sequence? $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n-2}}{4^{m+2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How would the limit of the following sequence be found.

$\displaystyle \frac{3^{n-2}}{4^{m+2}},\;$  as $\;n\rightarrow \infty$.

Would you use the squeeze theorem to find the limit of the sequence like this

$\displaystyle \frac{-3^m}{4^m}<\frac{3^{n-2}}{4^{m+2}}<\frac{3^m}{4^m}$

Comment: is this a kind of $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}$? (like, $a = \lim_{m,n\to \infty} a_{m,n}$ iff $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $\exists m_0,n_0$ such that $\forall n> n_0, \forall m > m_0$ $|a - a_{m,n}|<\varepsilon$?)

Comment: Not that it matters, but for the lower bound we can use $0$. For the upper bound, $\lt \frac{3^n}{4^n}$ is straightforward. Perhaps you are expected to **prove** that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n=0$.

Comment: Well the $(3/4)^n$ is one of the basic limits so I do not think it would need proof.... or does it?

Comment: Everything needs its proof ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$0 \lt \dfrac{3^{n - 2}}{4^{m+2}} \lt \dfrac {3^n}{4^n} = \left(\frac 34\right)^n$$

The limit, as $n\to \infty$, of each end doing the "squeezing" is $0$, so the limit of the squeezed term of your sequence must be $0$ as well.

Comment: This needs a TU! +1